# iOS: Increase spacing to UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, insets, uiedgeinsets

I made a custom `UINavigationBar` looks like this:[[image: 1]]

Now I want to increase spacing between left and left bar button. I tried to do that this way using `UIEdgeInsets` this way:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 0)
```

Then it gets shrieked [image: 2]]:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add extra spacing item before button:

```
    let button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "<", style: .plain, target: self, action: "someSelector")
    let spacing = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    spacing.width = 20;
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [spacing, button]
```